# My php() mail script wont send emails if the from address is from a yahoo email address

Tags: php, contact-form

The only problem is when the from field contains an e-mail
address that is from yahoo (example@yahoo.com) i dont see
the email in my inbox nor the junk folder.
Here is the script i use:

```
  <?php
  function spamcheck($field) {
    // Sanitize e-mail address
    $field=filter_var($field, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
    // Validate e-mail address
    if(filter_var($field, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
      return TRUE;
    } else {
      return FALSE;
    }
  }
    if ('POST' === $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) 
    {
    // Check if the "from" input field is filled out
    if (isset($_POST["from"])) {
      // Check if "from" email address is valid
      $mailcheck = spamcheck($_POST["from"]);
      if ($mailcheck==FALSE) {
        echo "Please enter a valid e-mail address";
      } else {
        $to = "xxxxx@xxxxxx.com";
        $from = filter_var($_POST["from"]); // sender
        $subject = $_POST["subject"];
        $message = $_POST["message"];
        // message lines should not exceed 70 characters (PHP rule), so wrap it
        $message = wordwrap($message, 70, "\r\n");
        $header='From: '.$from."\r\n";
        // send mail
        mail($to,$subject,$message,$header);
      }
    }
  }
  ?>
```

Comment: You need to send them using Yahoo's mail server.

Comment: I never wordwrapped my mail messages btw .. where did that "(PHP rule)" come from ? o.O

Comment: wordwrap function is helpful because it wraps the string into new lines when it reaches a specific length.

Comment: thanks for the replies though. ill give the yahoo mail server a try and let you guys know!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working with the use of the php mailer library (https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer).
Cheers!